# Avoir bonne/mauvaise réputation – absence d’article

Tags: absence-d-article

Pourquoi dit-on « il a bonne/mauvaise réputation » sans article, plutôt que « il a une bonne / une mauvaise réputation » ?

Je pensais d’abord que c’est à cause du verbe *avoir*, comme dans les expressions genre *avoir faim*, *avoir peur*, etc. Mais, si utilisées sans un adjectif, elles demandent un article : « il a une faim de loup. » Donc ce n’est pas le cas.

Alors, quelle est cette règle ? Y a-t-il d’autres expressions comme ça ? Ou c’est juste quelque chose d’historique et plutôt une exception ?

Merci pour vos idées !

Comment: "De loup" dans *faim de loup* n'est pas un adjectif... Remarquez qu'on dit *j'ai grand faim*... mais *j'ai une petite faim*... Et même chose avec *soif* !Je doute qu'il y ait un explication logique autre que "c'est comme ça", comme pour beaucoup d'expressions figées.

Answer (score 4):

Des expressions telles que « avoir bonne réputation » sont des expressions figées, que l'on trouve fréquemment dans les dictionnaires et qui, le plus souvent, doivent être complétées par une subordonnée ou une locution prépositive. Sont réunis ci-dessous quelques unes de ces expressions construites avec le verbe **« avoir »**, suivies de l'indication de comment les compléter ; toutes les possibilités ne sont pas prises en compte cependant (préposition la plus courante). Il existe des cas pour lesquels l'article peut s'utiliser, le sens pouvant alors être similaire ou différent, bien qu'ayant dans ce dernier cas une relation avec celui de l'expression sans article. Des cas « adjectif zéro » ont été ajoutés. Cette liste  et les indications que l'on y trouve sont très certainement loin d'être exhaustives.

- avoir grand [faim](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+grand+faim%2Cj%27ai+une+grande+faim&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20grand%20faim%3B%2Cc0)
- avoir grand [soif](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+grand+soif%2Cavoir+une+grande+soif&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20grand%20soif%3B%2Cc0)
- avoir grand [espoir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+grand+espoir+*%2Cavoir+grand+espoir&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20grand%20espoir%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20grand%20espoir%3B%2Cc0) (de)  *<sub>« Avoir un grand [espoir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+un+grand+espoir&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20un%20grand%20espoir%3B%2Cc0) » se dit aussi, mais le sens est différent.</sub>*
- avoir bonne/mauvaise [conscience](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+bonne+conscience&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20bonne%20conscience%3B%2Cc0)
- avoir [idée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+dans+l%27id%C3%A9e+que%2Cavoir+id%C3%A9e+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20dans%20l%27%20id%C3%A9e%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20du%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20d%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavoir%20id%C3%A9e%20en%3B%2Cc0) (de, que) *<sub>On dit plutôt « j'ai dans l'idée (que/de) ».</sub>*
- avoir [raison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+raison+de%2Cavoir+une+raison+de&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20raison%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20une%20raison%20de%3B%2Cc0) (de) *<sub>« Avoir une raison de » se dit mais n'est pas une expression figée et n'a pas le même sens.</sub>*
- avoir [mémoire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai++m%C3%A9moire+de&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20m%C3%A9moire%20de%3B%2Cc0) (de)
- avoir (un) [intérêt](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt%2Cavoir+un+int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20un%20int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt%3B%2Cc0) (à) *<sub>« Avoir un intérêt à » se dit mais n'est pas une expression figée et n'a pas tout à fait le même sens.</sub>*
- avoir bon/mauvais [esprit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+mauvais+esprit%2Cavoir+bon+esprit&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20mauvais%20esprit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20bon%20esprit%3B%2Cc0)
- avoir grand [peur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+grand+peur+*%2Cavoir+une+grande+peur+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20grand%20peur%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20une%20grande%20peur%20de%3B%2Cc0) (de, que) *<sub>« Avoir une grand**e** peur (de, des) » se dit mais n'est pas une expression figée et n'a pas le même sens.</sub>*
- il y a belle [lurette](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+y+a+belle+lurette%2Cil+y+a+une+belle+lurette&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20belle%20lurette%3B%2Cc0) (que)

---

- avoir (une) bonne/mauvaise [intention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+bonne+intention%2Cont+mauvaise+intention&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20bonne%20intention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cont%20mauvaise%20intention%3B%2Cc0)  *<sub>On dit aussi « avoir de bonnes/mauvaises intentions » avec le même sens.</sub>*
- avoir (une) bonne/mauvaise [réputation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+une+bonne+r%C3%A9putation%2Cavoir+bonne+r%C3%A9putation&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20une%20bonne%20r%C3%A9putation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20bonne%20r%C3%A9putation%3B%2Cc0) (dans, parmi, chez)
- avoir (une) grande  [envie](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+grande+envie%2Cj%27ai+une+grande+envie&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20grande%20envie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20une%20grande%20envie%3B%2Cc0) (de)
- avoir (un) grand [souci](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+grand+souci+de%2Cavoir+un+grand+souci+de&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20grand%20souci%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavoir%20un%20grand%20souci%20de%3B%2Cc0) (de)
- avoir (une) belle [apparence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+belle+apparence%2Cont+belle+apparence&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20belle%20apparence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cont%20belle%20apparence%3B%2Cc0)

---

- avoir une bonne [raison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+bonne+raison%2Cj%27ai+une+bonne+raison&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20une%20bonne%20raison%3B%2Cc0) (de croire, de penser) *<sub>On dit aussi « j'ai bonne raison » mais ce serait comparativement rare.</sub>*

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a malheureusement pas de réponses à ce problème, c'est tout simplement une **exception** de la langue française

**Supposition:**

Language Familier: (avec article)

> Il a une bonne/mauvaise réputation.

Language Soutenu: (sans article)

> Il a bonne/mauvaise réputation.

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement les quelques exemples cités sont des exceptions.

Ils peuvent toutefois s'écrire avec ou sans article.

> J'ai grand appétit ce soir.
>
> J'ai un grand appétit ce soir.

Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de règles pour savoir quelles expressions peut se passer d'article.